# Regular expression in Python / Pygame to identify keypressed

Tags: python, regex, pygame

I have a quick question for which I haven't found a solution so far.
I'm working on a small app using Pygame for which I need to identify if the keyboard key pressed by the user is between a certain range, for example between A and F only. For this, I'm using a regular expression and it is working just fine if the user is pressing a letter or a number. Everything outside the regular expression is ignored.
My problem is when the user presses a none alphanumeric key, like space, escape, arrows as, while they are not in my range, they get accepted by the regular expression.

Here is an example:

```
import pygame, re
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 800, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

AppExit = False

while not AppExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        # check if pressed key is between A and F
                        keypressed = pygame.key.name(event.key)
                        isValidLetter = re.search('[a-f]', keypressed)
                        if isValidLetter is not None:
                                print(keypressed + " is between A and F")

        pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

If you run this code and, for example, press Escape you'll get a print "ESCAPE is between A and F" in the console.

I can't find how to exclude those keys :(

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well try it in the interpreter

```
re.search('[A-Z]', 'ESCAPE')
# --> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='E'>
```

which isn't None. That's because there is an `A`, a `C` and two `E`s in `ESCAPE` which are matched.

What you want is

```
re.match('^[A-Z]$', 'ESCAPE')  # None
re.match('^[A-Z]$', 'E')  # match object
```

since `^` matches the beginning of the string and `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you so much for this working solution... I tried the match expression before I posted my message but without the ^ and $, that's why it didn't worked. Thank you so much again !

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`event.unicode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) attribute instead of `pygame.key.name(event.key)`:

```
keypressed = event.unicode
```

Comment: Skrx, thanks, your solution works too (of course) but was less compliant with the rest of my code... at least, without having to rewrite everything ;)  Thank you again :)